# Custom format for a NSNumber to NSString conversion

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have on my application a `UITextField` that receives a number.

I want that this number to be represented in a particular format, like this: `(62) 1234 1234`

The problem is: i already have control over the method `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` but i dont know how can i make this "mask"

Currently i`m doing like this:

```
string = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:string];
NSLog(@"%@", myNumber);
```

at the end of this code i have 2 things:

1. string : the string representation of my text ( e.g. `6212341234` as a `NSString` )
2. myNumber : the number for this string ( e.g. `6212341234` as a `NSNumber` )

how can i create this string: `(62) 1234 1234` based on `myNumber` or `string` ?

**EDIT**

Responding to rdelmar question:

The number can have 10 or 11 numbers, and i intent to separate them like this:
`(62) 1234 1234` or `(62) 12345 1234`

Comment: Are the numbers always 10 digits? And, do you always want to separate it the way you show above?

Comment: Is this actually a phone number? Looks like it, from the format that you are trying to achieve. If so, treat it as a string and use substrings.

Comment: this is not a phone number, could be treated as one now that i think of it. but how should i do it?

Comment: If it was a phone number, you could reason about it in terms of area codes like "(62)" or "(4)" and then group the rest according to conventions. Phone number formatting is different for various locales in terms of grouping. It is also very different from normal number grouping, i.e. not based on quantities like thousands.

Comment: ok... i see your point. but i still have no idea on how to implement this solution. can you formulate an answer and post it as an answer?

Comment: See the answer by @rdelmar below; uses substrings as I sketched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NSRegularExpression`...

```
- (NSString *) formattedString:(NSString *)inputString
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:([0-9]{2})([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4}))|(?:([0-9]{0,2}+)([0-9]{0,4}+)([0-9]{0,4}+))" options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *components = [NSArray array];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:inputString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length])];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    for ( NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 3; ++i )
    {
        NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
        if ( NSNotFound == range.location )
        {
            break;
        }
        components = [components arrayByAddingObject:[inputString substringWithRange:range]];
    }
    if ( 0 == [components count] )
    {
        for ( NSUInteger i = 4; i <= 6; ++i )
        {
            NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
            components = [components arrayByAddingObject:[inputString substringWithRange:range]];
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@ %@",
            [components objectAtIndex:0],
            [components objectAtIndex:1],
            [components objectAtIndex:2]];
}


- (void) testFormatting
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"62123451234"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"6212341234"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"621234123"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"62123412"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"6212341"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"621234"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"62123"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"6212"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"621"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"62"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedString:@"6"]);
}
```

The result of calling the `testFormatting` method is:

```
(62) 12345 1234
(62) 1234 1234
(62) 1234 123
(62) 1234 12
(62) 1234 1
(62) 1234 
(62) 123 
(62) 12 
(62) 1 
(62)  
(6)
```

This way you could pass intermediate strings to the formatter and it would try to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this (for 10 digit numbers):

```
-(NSString *)formatString:(NSString *) input {
    NSString *part1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[input substringToIndex:2]];
    NSString *part2 = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
    NSString *part3 = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 4)];
    NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",part1,part2,part3];
    return formatted;

}
```

To handle 10 or 11 digit numbers you would have to put in an if clause to test the length, and then change the ranges of part2 and part3 accordingly.

After Edit: How about something like this. I think this is about as good as can be done. It will break it into (xx) xxxx xxxx as you type, and if you type another digit it will break it into (xx) xxxxx xxxx. Any further input is ignored.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField.text.length == 0)
     textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@",textField.text];

    if (textField.text.length == 3)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@) ",textField.text];

    if (textField.text.length == 9)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",textField.text];

    if (textField.text.length == 14) {
        NSString *part1 = [textField.text substringToIndex:9];
        part1 = [part1 stringByAppendingString:[textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, 1)]];
        NSString *part2 = [textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 3)];
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",part1,part2];
    }

    if (textField.text.length > 14)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: in my application the string formatting is made at the same time the user types a new digit. because of this i dont have the full string with the 10-11 digits. because of that ``substringWithRange:`` wont work

Comment: You should have mentioned that at the start.  I don't think there's any way to get it perfectly right as you type because there's no way to know whether the user is going to enter an 11 digit or 10 digit number. So, the break between the last 2 parts can't be determined until the last digit is entered.